# Selecting an element by id inside a DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to select an element by id, that is already existing inside a created DOM element?

For example:

```
var domElement = $('#id1');
domElement.find('#id2').value = '';
```

Comment: Your use of `.value` on the jquery object is incorrect, it should be `.val('')`

Comment: There is no need to find element by id inside another element found by id. Selecting by ID is unambiguous so if you want to get an element with id `id2` then just select it by `$('#id2')`. Is that what you're asking for?

Comment: You should be directly able to change the value for that id `$('#id2').val('SOME_VALUE')`, no need to find it as above. **Id's are unique**

Comment: "*Is it possible to select an element by id, that is already existing inside a created DOM element?*" - yes, what happened when you tried it?   Did it fail because you used `.value`?  Try something else like `.hide()`.   This is a non-question as it takes less than 10 seconds to try it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's completely possible - and it even works with nested elements:

```js
$("#button").on("click", () => {
  var domElement = $("#id1");
  domElement.find("#id2").value = "Different text!";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<div id="id1">
  <div>
    <section>
      <input id="id2" type="text" value="Text">
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
<button id="button">Click me!</button>
```

As [@freefaller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/930393/freefaller) pointed out in the comments, using `value` with a jQuery object may not work on some browsers (I think it only works on Safari), so use `val` instead:

```js
$("#button").on("click", () => {
  var domElement = $("#id1");
  domElement.find("#id2").val("Different text!");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<div id="id1">
  <div>
    <section>
      <input id="id2" type="text" value="Text">
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
<button id="button">Click me!</button>
```

Comment: Did you try running your script?  It should be `.val()` instead of `.value=`

Comment: @freefaller Yes, I ran my script (press the `Run code snippet` button), and also, they are pretty much interchangeable (bar the error-throwing issue), but `val` is jQuery's version, and `value` is plain JS (I'm sticking to the OP's code as much as possible).

Comment: Then I'm seeing a very strange outcome, as I get no change on the input (via Firefox)... as I'm pretty sure they're not interchangable

Comment: Just to confirm, it doesn't work on Chrome for me either (via Windows 10)

Comment: Oh yes - my bad, must be a Safari thing.

Comment: OK @freefaller, fixed now, any better?

Comment: Yep, nice one. I never use Safari, so wasn't aware of the cross over.  I'm not sure how accurate it is, but my rule of thumb is that you just don't use properties on jQuery